# Can infinitely many collinear disconnected (open) line segments cover a finite length?

Tags: geometry, infinity

An infinite number of points can definitely cover a finite length – any line segment satisfies that condition.

An infinite number of collinear connected (closed) line segments can definitely cover a finite length – one can always subdivide any segment infinitely many times.

But can an infinite number of collinear disconnected (open) line segments cover a finite length?

For completeness, I'm using the [Wikipedia definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment#In_real_or_complex_vector_spaces) for *open segment* and *closed segment*, and by "*cover a finite length*" I mean that all points in the (infinitely many) segments should belong to a finite line segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\subseteq (0,1)$.